# Upload file. After uploading will be save in the place where i have stated

Tags: php, upload, docx

I would like to upload a docx to this location "C:\XAMMP\htdocs\FYP3\uploads/" 
Below are my codes for uploading the file. For now, after i click on upload, i cannot even find my file in the given address. Not sure what the error is. Thanks in advance:)

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']))
        {
            $file=$_FILES['file'];


            $file_name=$file['name'];
            $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
            $file_size = $file['size'];
            $file_error = $file['error'];

            $file_ext = explode('.',$file_name);
            $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

            $allowed=array('docx', 'jpg');

            if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed))
            {
                if($file_error === 0)
                {
                    if($file_size <= 2097152)
                    {
                        $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                        $file_destination = "C:\XAMMP\htdocs\FYP3\uploads/" . $file_name_new;

                        if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination))
                        {
                            echo $file_destination;
                        }



                    }
                }
            }


        }
```

Below is my form code:)

```
<form action="homepage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" value="upload">


    </form>
```

Comment: Post also the form please

Comment: @ClaudioKing Edited:) Thank you!

Comment: Use like this way. `$file_destination = "uploads/" . $file_name_new;` And, respond back

Answer (score 0):

First of all please check the method attribute of , it must be post and then check its enc-type attribute, it must be multipart-form data. If these both things are OK, then in your Php code block use print_r($file) if the form posted the file successfully then this will print all the properties of that file. If every thing is fine till this point then check the destination path and directory permission, may be you dont have the permission to write the file. I think "C:\XAMMP\htdocs\FYP3\uploads/" . $file_name_new; the last slash "uploads/" is in wrong format. Please check it.
That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The `$file_destination` is incorrect in two ways: "XAMMP" is misspelled, it should be "XAMPP". And you have to use "\\" or "/" as the path seperator.

```
$file_destination = "C:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\FYP3\\uploads\\" . $file_name_new;
```

Also you should check if the destination directory is created and writeable using [is_writable()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-writable.php).

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in destination path. Try this:

Replace

```
$file_destination = "C:\XAMMP\htdocs\FYP3\uploads/" . $file_name_new;
```

with

```
$file_destination = "C:/XAMMP/htdocs/FYP3/uploads/" . $file_name_new;
```